# Get data from primary and foreign key relationship tables using angularjs in mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 tables `Collection`, `Subcollection` and `Products`.

`Collection` table id uses as forgien key in `Subcollection` and `Products` table. And Sub.... table id is used as a foreign key in `Products` table.

Now I am trying to get a list of collections from `Collection` using angular js. But I am not getting anything in the view. In console the error shows. When I click on error it goes to error:

> ngRepeat:dupes
>   Duplicate Key in Repeater.

But when I try to get data of another table in which no any relation it's working so I want to know how I get data from table whose relation with another table with foreign key. I am also trying track by `$index` but that's not working

```html
  public JsonResult getcolldata()
       {
           var lst = eShoppingEntitiesContetxt.Collections.Where(x => x.IsActive  == true).ToList();
           var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst, new JsonSerializerSettings
           {
               ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
           });
           return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

```js
<!-- AppModule -->
var app = angular.module("StudentApp", []);

<!-- Service -->
app.service("EmployeeService", function ($http) {
    this.getEmployee = function () {
       
        return $http.get("/User/getcolldata");
    };
});

<!-- Controller -->
app.controller("StudentController", function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
  
    GetAllEmployee();

    function GetAllEmployee() {       
        $scope.name = "Sample";
     
        var getAllEmployee = EmployeeService.getEmployee();
        getAllEmployee.then(function (emp) {                    
           $scope.employees = emp.data;          
        }, function () {
            alert('Data not found');
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/AppModule.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Controller.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Services.js"></script>

<div ng-app="StudentApp" class="container">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Student" ng-model="searchStudent" />
    <br />
    <div ng-controller="StudentController">

        <table class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in employees | filter : searchStudent" >
                <td>{{ r.Col_Title }}</td>              
                
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This is my collection table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kikpc.png)  [This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ohtW.png)

Comment: Any one help me to sort out this problem

Comment: The error is just in the view, Could you share the repeater html and also the script on how you bind the data to the angular modal ? It is possible that the binding is done on the wrong object returned and not the actual data..

Comment: I have updated my question with full script and  HTML. so now you can check my code easily

Comment: please share `console.log(emp.data)` that is returned.

Comment: it returns angular.js:12520 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=r%20in%20collections%20%7C%20filter%20%3A%20searchStudent&p1=string%3A%22&p2=%22
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:27518
    at Object.fn (angular.js:15763)
    at r.$digest (angular.js:15896)
    at r.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at g (angular.js:10589)
    at T (angular.js:10787)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:10728)

Comment: I know the reason is duplicate values and keys in the json due to foreign key in table. but i want solution of this. is this draw back of angular 1

Comment: `console.log(emp.data)` should be the collection output you are getting from the service/endpoint, if it executed correctly. You shared the error output from angular.